# Box not showing up css

Tags: css

My code worked on the W3school's Tryit Editor, but won't work on a browser.

Here's my html:

```
<div align="center">
    <div class id="welcome">
        <iframe src="http://www.cartoonnetwork.com/games/adventuretime/righteousquest/game.swf" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br/><br/>
        <h1>Adventure Time:Righteous Quest</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And heres my css:

```
.welcome{    
    border:1px solid white;
    margin:0px;
    color:#000000;
    background:#ffffff;     
}
```

Also, I've tried it without the div align and it produced the same results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the border color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**replace**

```
 <div class id="welcome">
```

**With**

```
 <div class="welcome">
```

because you used class `.welcome` in css. if you want to use `id` , you need to define your css as `#welcome`.

Comment: Oh god, I can't believe I didn't see that one. It was right in front of me but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user2203843 its ok anyone can make mistake , but i think now your problem is solved ?

Comment: Yes it did solve it thank you. Its those tiny mistakes that always ruin me. lol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your html.  You need to change:

```
<div class id="welcome">
```

to

```
<div class="welcome">
```

**See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lflores/qWMHS/**

Comment: The same answer has given a far before.

Comment: I saw that after I posted my answer.  I must have been working on the fiddle - hopefully that helps the person who asked the question as it looks like they are new to HTML/CSS.

Comment: I'm actually not a beginner. I don't know how I missed a tiny mistake like that, but I assure you. 'Twas just a fluke.

Comment: My mistake.  It's not uncommon to overlook little things.  Sometimes it's the little things that get us the most often!  That's one of the benefits of SO - to get fresh eyes to look at it.